# How to run background job and keep looking something in parse cloud to perform action

Tags: android, parse-platform, cloud

Hello I want to keep running one background job always on parse cloud and keep looking such that whenever any row insert in table then I want to perform some operation like send notification to user automatically via that background job.

If it is possible then what is way to have this in parse ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `beforeSave` method of Parse's in cloud code. 
An example of a before save function is shown below, but this could also be triggered after the object is saved, with `afterSave`. All of this can be found on Parse.com's documentation

In javascript:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Review", function(request, response) {
  if (request.object.get("stars") < 1) {
    response.error("you cannot give less than one star");
  } else if (request.object.get("stars") > 5) {
    response.error("you cannot give more than five stars");
  } else {
    response.success();
  }
});
```

Found at the parse documentation: `https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-onsave`